# Is there any way to remove the bcc tag when using the SMTP library?

Tags: python, email, automation, smtplib

I'm trying to make an email bot for my buddy. However, when I send the test emails, they will have a bcc tag, which he can't have. Is there any way to bypass this?
This is my code:

````
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

e = pd.read_excel('email.xlsx')
emails = e['Emails'].values

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("email", "password")
msg = "hello world!"
subject = "test"
To = emails
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg)

for email in emails:
    server.sendmail("email", email, body)
    print("Email Sent!")
server.quit()```
````

Comment: also, I don't have any tags yet, however, the list is imported through pandas and an excel file.

Comment: `BCC` header is typically removed by SMTP server.

Comment: @AnFi i mean the actual box that it fills in on the physical email. It needs to just say to: <recipient email>. but the box stays empty